# Where can I obtain data on flood sites, land sewage systems, and property value?

Tags: data, elevation, flood, land-use

I am a college student trying to obtain this data for a class project. If anyone can help that would be great. Basically, my hypothesis for this project is that land sewage systems that have not been recently upgraded lead to flooding, thus, lead to a decrease in property value. I would like to obtain data in Chicago, but any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like it has been done http://www.isws.illinois.edu/data.asp Hazard Mitigation Grant Program

Comment: https://msc.fema.gov/portal?

Comment: Flood zones is fairly easy - FEMA of course as Alex mentions, but the county often has this data in GIS form as well. Property values may be available through the assessor's office. Your county or city GIS office may have readily available data to use. I know Lake County, which is near Chicago, is pretty GIS savvy. I'm not clear on what you mean by land sewage systems though - do you mean sanitary sewer networks or septic tank systems? In either case, you're again looking at county government. Particularly engineering/wastewater for network age, building/permit dept. for septic upgrades.